# If investors face different tax rates, how can an asset pricing model be built so that it satisfies the incentive constraints of both investors?

Tags: asset-pricing, econometrics, modelling

The CAPM and other models have been expanded to include the impact of corporate/personal taxes. However, what if these tax rates differ for an investor pool holding the same equity stake (which by definition, has the same value for all), how would this asset be priced? In my opinion, the return cannot compensate both investors but will always over/under compensate one of them? What is the incentive of the under compensated investor to hold this stock? Or would this simply lead to differences in portfolios rather than differences in the discount rate?